# How to convert a list to CSV with Vim?

Tags: list, csv, vim

I want this list:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

to come out as:

`one,two,three,four,five,six`

if I use Vim's search and replace like:

`:%s/\n/,/g`

it will come out like:

`one,two,three,four,five,six,`

Is there a way to avoid the last comma?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/can-i-join-lines-with-a-comma-or-another-character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it with a single substitution:

```
:%s/\n\(.\)/,\1
```

`\n` matches every newline, including the one on the last line, so we leave the last newline out by adding the character immediately after the newline. That character is put in a capture group to allow us to reuse it in the replacement part.

Frankly, the following does the job with the same amount of keystrokes but with a lot less head scratching:

```
:%s/\n/,|norm $x
```

Comment: First solution worked and made me give myself a good headscratch! Learned something, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could append a comma to all but the last line before running the substitution command (see `:help :normal`):

`:1,$-1 norm A,`

Then of course don't add a comma during the substitution:

`:%s/\n`